# How to create user command without a capital letter as first letter?

Tags: linux, user-commands

I know I can set user-defined commands using the `:command Foo bar` syntax, but I want a way to set a command without using capitals.

For example, to save all open buffers, the command is `:wa`, but that's slightly too inconvenient. I'd really like to be able to just do `:ww`.

What's with this seemingly arbitrary limitation? Why do I have to use capital letters?

Comment: https://github.com/kana/vim-altercmd/blob/master/doc/altercmd.txt

Comment: @VanLaser After installing that, I'm able to run `:AlterCommand ww wa` in the actual vim instance and have it work, but I can't add it to my .vimrc properly.

I've tried
`AlterCommand ww wa`
`:AlterCommand ww wa`
and a few variations of that.

I'm not even sure what to Google for this? What are these "commands" called that have colons before them? And how do I add them to my vimrc?

Comment: To use `AlterCommand` in your `vimrc`, you will need to place this command somewhere above (still in your `vimrc`): `call altercmd#load()`. It's documented in the plugin's help. BTW, the whole plugin is a convenient interface around Vim's builtin `cnoreabbrev` command. Also those "commands" with colons before them are called ... Vim commands (and they are run from "command-line mode").

Comment: Thanks for having patience, I appreciate it.

I was reading http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2675 and didn't see it there, but I looked at the other docs and I'm seeing it now.

Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. You can always use `:h altercmd`, `:h cnoreabbrev` and so on.

Comment: `:h user-cmd-ambiguous`

Comment: Also, if you have 'ignorecase' set, you can tab-complete a lower-case prefix to a user-defined command.

Answer (score 4):

#### Why

Commands (custom as well as built-in) are used in mappings, scripts, plugins. If you could override them, it would be very easy to break functionality.

There is a mechanism for customization that doesn't suffer from this (command-line mode abbreviations); unfortunately, they don't differentiate (between commands and arguments, or commands and searches), so they are too coarse, especially for short tweaks (like `:W` → `:w`). Try that:

```
:Alias ww wa
```

#### Plugin

The [cmdalias.vim - Create aliases for Vim commands](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=746) plugin attempts to solve this problem, by defining mappings that only apply in command positions.